# Using mysqli_change_user, or not?

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

I am setting up a database class in my php application, and I was planning on using either PDO or MySQLi.
I was thinking of persistant connections, but I am wondering if this is the best idea. I saw, unlike PDO, MySQLi automaticly resets the state of the connection with `mysqli_change_user()`.

However, [as noted in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php), it states that the `mysqli_change_user()` function is expensive and could degrade performance, but that you can also disable it.

I currently have two questions:

- Are persistant connections a good idea? And if so, with PDO or MySQLi?
- Is the `mysqli_change_user()` function so expensive that it nullifies the performance increase of using a persistant connection? If so, is it such a bad idea to disable it, if you have written proper code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are persistant connections a good idea?

Nope, as a rule, it's not. Especially given with mysqli_change_user() its benefits become close to nil.

> And if so, with PDO or MySQLi?

Given only mysqli changes the user, it's is the only choice.

> Is the mysqli_change_user() function so expensive that it nullifies the performance increase of using a persistant connection?

Yes, it is

> If so, is it such a bad idea to disable it, if you have written proper code?

Yes, it's bad. It's not about a proper code but about fatal errors. A single script that fatally crashed and didn't release a lock or commit a transaction may wreak a havoc. That's why, exactly, mysqli_change_user() was came to be.

In all, I wouldn't bother with persistent connections at all

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate answer. I was suspecting it wouldn't degrade performance by a large margin, but I wanted to make sure. I'll stick with using `mysqli_change_user()` I think.

Comment: Thank you, whoever DV-ed the answer, it was all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Persistent connections is generally known to actually have an adverse effect to performance. We've had a lot of trouble with it on high traffic sites.

Comment: This is interesting, you would think it would actually increase performance.

Comment: it just require some tweaking from the other side too.

Comment: Opening tcp sockets is acually quite cheap. With persistent connections you actually need to keep a connection open for every fork of the webserver/php process. Many of our pages only open a database connection upon the first query, and many things are cached to an extent where sometimes there's no query at all.

So databases running 200-300 processes means 300 open database connections.

Comment: So yea, we noticed keeping a small amount of sockets open beats the tiny benefit of not having to establish a new connetion.